# Batch API callback method is not call

Tags: batch-operations

Here is my source:

```
function sc_delete_user_confirm_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
   //...
      $batch = array(
        'operations' => array(),
        'finished' => 'user_delete_tickets_batch_finished',
        'title' => t('Processing delete user tickets'),
        'init_message' => t('Deleting user tickets is starting.'),
        'progress_message' => t('Processing...'),
        'error_message' => t('Deleting user tickets has encountered an error.'),
      );
      $batch['operations'][] = array('user_delete_tickets_batch_process', array());
      batch_set($batch);
  //...
}

function user_delete_tickets_batch_process(&$context) {
  watchdog('my_module', 'user_delete_tickets_batch_process ENTER!', array(),  WATCHDOG_ERROR);
  //...
}

function user_delete_tickets_batch_finished($success, $results, $operations) {
  watchdog(my_module', 'user_delete_tickets_batch_finished ENTER!', array(), WATCHDOG_ERROR);
  //...
}
```

I see progress bar but it not call my callback method `user_delete_tickets_batch_process` (I didn't see log in `/admin/reports/dblog`), also it not call `user_delete_tickets_batch_finished`.
What is wrong in this my source.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifing the file where your functions are located.

Even if those functions are in the same file as your #submit callback, the `file` path may be needed.

```
$batch = array(
  'operations' => array(),
  'finished' => 'user_delete_tickets_batch_finished',
  'title' => t('Processing delete user tickets'),
  'init_message' => t('Deleting user tickets is starting.'),
  'progress_message' => t('Processing...'),
  'error_message' => t('Deleting user tickets has encountered an error.'),
  'file' => drupal_get_path('module', 'your_module') . '/your_module.module'
);
```